# Run controller method each 5 seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, task

i'm new to ruby...
How can i do, that my controller's method start's automatically each 5 seconds? What i need fot this? Where to read about? And how to do?

Now my method is:

```
 def start_new_solving
    @session = Session.new
    @user = User.find(:first, conditions: {free: true})
    @secret = Secret.find(:first, conditions: {status: "uploaded"})
    if @user.present? && @secret.present?
      @session.status = "start solving"
      @session.user_id = @user.id
    end
    @session.save!
    @secret.update_attributes(status: "start solving")
  end
```

Please give example. Thank you)

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following:

```
  Thread.new do
     while true do
       sleep 5
       start_new_solving
     end
   end
```

This will execute the method as you ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [clockwork](https://github.com/adamwiggins/clockwork) gem.

Answer (score 0):

Rails runs your controller methods when the application receives the corresponding request. For example:

```
http://localhost:3000/solver/start_new_solving
```

could call `SolverController`'s `start_new_solving` method.

To run a controller method again after 5 seconds, the browser just has to reload the page, e.g. via JavaScript:

```
setTimeout("location.reload(true);", 5000)
```